# Change a header (default type) of specific file type called in admin section of website (nested configuration?)

Tags: nginx, http-headers

How could I change header (default type) of `js` files with the admin pages ?

```
location /admin {
   #forwarded to varnish
   proxy_pass http://specificurl:81/admin

   # not working when reloading configuration:
   location ~* \.js$ {
      default_type plain/text;
   } 
}
```

... as nginx doesn't support nested conf.

The error given are :

```
Nov 05 11:54:37 myservv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 05 11:54:37 myservv systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't terminated your `proxy_pass` directive with an Semicolon.

You get more info on Errors by Testing your configuarion with `nginx -tc /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` before reloading.
With that you get the following Error:

```
2018/11/05 12:15:42 [emerg] 8368#8368: directive "proxy_pass" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf:37
```

Hope that was the only Problem.

(Paths can variate in your configuration depending on your System etc.)